# Unable to get the RowDifferences property of the Range class

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data in the active spreadsheet:

```
A    B
---  ---
a    a
b
c
d
e
```

where `B1` is currently the active cell.

The following code in the Debug pane:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5").RowDifferences(ActiveCell)
```

fails with:

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the RowDifference property of the Range class

**What is the proper usage of the `RowDifferences` property?**

---

**Update**

I get the same error when using `ColumnDifferences` for the above data.

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("A").ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell)
```

Even when I transpose the data:

```
A   B   C   D   E
--- --- --- --- ---
a   b   c   d   e
a
```

and set `A2` as the active cell, I get the same error for:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).RowDifferences(ActiveCell)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you use `ColumnDifferences` for `Range("A1:A5")`?

Comment: If you're using `ColumnDifferences`, your comparison cell needs to be in the same column - i.e. use A1.

Comment: @BigBen Your last comment appears to be the solution; please post as an answer.

Comment: @BigBen aha! Nice one, you caught it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `ColumnDifferences` since `Range("A1:A5")` is a column in this case.
2. If you're using `RowDifferences` or `ColumnDifferences`, the comparison cell **must** be located in the `Range` you are comparing, e.g. use `A1` and not `B1`.

To demonstrate further, I added additional values in `B1:B5`. With `A1` as the comparison cell, here are the results of `RowDifferences` and `ColumnDifferences` (`Select`ing the result).

**Row Differences**

```
Sub TestRowDiff()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set rng = .Range("A1:B5").RowDifferences(.Range("A1"))
    End With

    rng.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Here `B1:B5` is selected - Excel checks rows 1 - 5, comparing the cells in Column A to Column B, by row. The letter "f" is not the same as "a", "g" is not the same as "b" and so on.

**Column Differences**

```
Sub TestColDiff()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set rng = .Range("A1:B5").ColumnDifferences(.Range("A1"))
    End With

    rng.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Here `A2:B5` are selected since "b" through "e" are not the same as "a", and "g" through "j" are not the same as "f".

Answer (score 1):

As @BigBen said in the comments, you might be looking for `ColumnDifferences` here.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-rowdifferences-method-excel) is the MSDN documentation for `RowDifferences`

And [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-columndifferences-method-excel) it is for `ColumnDifferences`

You should end up with something like:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("A").ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell)
```

Comment: This doesn't work either; I've updated the question.

Comment: Btw, your range doesn't need to be one full horizontal row..., just like A1:A5 is not a full column.

Comment: @BigBen I think that's just me assuming from the documentation again! Does it take any shaped range, or just single column for ColumnDifferences, single row for RowDifferences (but it doesn't have to be full Column/Row)? Is that right?

Comment: Shaped range - it can handle multiple columns/rows. I'm adding that detail in my answer.

Comment: @BigBen no worries, I'll just take the errors out of my answer for longevity and leave the rest for you!